# Application Gauss equation

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Get M ,compact , an oriented minimal immersed surface of $S^3$. In the case where M is a minimal surface, the Gauss equation, gives us a relation
between the norm of the shape operator, $||A||^2$, and the Gauss curvature of the surface, K. Namely,

$K=1- \frac{||A||^2}{2}$

Where $||A||$ is the norm of the second fundamental form.

I tried use the Gauss equation for the curvature tensor to show it, but it isn't clear for me. Maybe its necessary use other equation, any suggestion?

Comment: It is not good behavior here to post the same question several times. I asked you a few questions the previous time; you answered one in your repost, but not the other. How about it? And yes, it is the Gauss equation if you interpret it correctly and know what the norm of II is.

Comment: Sorry, it was bad. I revised the teory and I am using $\lt \overline R(X,Y)Z,T \gt = \lt R(X,Y)Z,T \gt -\lt B(Y,T),B(X,Z)\gt + \lt B(X,T),B(Y,Z) \gt$, but $M$ in $S^3$, is it correct formulae?

reference for "Gauss equation" is manfredo, Carmo.

Comment: You *still* have not answered my question. Moreover, this is a surface, so how do you get $K$? It seems you’re not learning the basics. Do so.